# Power in garage?

Tags: electrical

I tore down a old shed that had power in it ( from house on 12-2 wire). Can I put in a new square D box with 6 circuits run by the same 12-2 cable? How to?

Comment: 12/2 gets you 20a 120v. 6 circuits sounds like a bit much.

Comment: More details will get better answers, what kind of cable, buried or in a conduit, where you are mounting the new box. We got 800 pages of rules, and almost no details.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  But you may not find it worthwhile.

### You cannot run 240V on that setup.  That means you'll be running a 120V panel.

Since it's an outbuilding, you will need a "disconnect switch". Typically one uses a main-breaker panel to get the disconnect.  I recommend this because I recommend *way more spaces than you expect to use*, so you have expansion room for the future.

If you use one of those tiny 4-8 space panels, those don't have main breakers, so you must install a breaker in the normal area and backfeed. The ampacity of this breaker will not matter.  The backfeed breaker must be tied down, and that will probably force you to use a 2-pole breaker since they won't sell tie-down kits for 1-poles.

Anyway, regardless, you split your #12 supply wire so it serves both legs of the disconnect/main breaker.

Now you can put as many 120V loads as you please in the various breaker spaces. **Do not do multi-wire branch circuits (MWBC or shared-neutral!!)**  And 240V loads will not work.

### If you really need 240V there, you'll need a transformer for 120V

> A friend is only a friend until you sell him something. Then, he's a customer." - Quark from Star Trek

For lots of people, they might have a 240V table saw that doesn't need neutral. And LED lighting that's happy-dappy on 240V and doesn't need neutral.  And then, y'know, a dust collector or tool battery charger that does need 120V.  Can you steal neutral from ground? NO!!! If you do that, then ground isn't ground anymore.  It's neutral.  That changes everything about safety: a neutral wire break pretty much guarantees all your grounds are energized! What a dangerous situation!

So the only way to source 120V is to have a transformer make 120V from the 240V.  5 KVA supply transformers are often seen for $150 on Craigslist, and can easily take 240V off your supply and turn that into a **separately derived service** of 120/240V split-phase.  Though it's easy with transformers to exceed the cost of simply installing a larger 4-wire feeder.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. You need  a 4 wire service (2 hots, a neutral and a ground) as well as locally installed ground rods near your (apparently) new shed or outbuilding, unless you have very minimal power requirements.    This subject has been discussed over and over here, so I suggest you do some searches and you'll find a wealth of information.   Also, please take the tour so you'll know how to best participate here.

Answer (score 1):

12/2 UF could feed a single 120 volt 20 amp circuit to a new shed or building that has no other feed. Any splice would need listed for direct burial or in an accessible box.

But a 6 circuit panel is mostly pointless. For the single 120v 20A circuit you only need a disconnect switch, like a light 20A rated light switch. If you install a panel (maybe for a future larger feeder) you would need two spaces for a backfeed disconnect, leaving four spaces for circuits.

If you run a larger feeder you would then need to install ground rod(s).